# Judges 1:16 translation difference

Tags: judges

In Judges 1:16 (NASB)

> Now the descendants of the Kenite, Moses’ father-in-law, went up from the city of palms with the sons of Judah, to the wilderness of Judah which is in the south of Arad; and **they went and lived with the people**.

Yet, the same verse in Good News Translation

> The descendants of Moses' father-in-law, the Kenite, went on with the people of Judah from Jericho, the city of palm trees, into the barren country south of Arad in Judah. **There they settled among the Amalekites**.

What's the reason for this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNT has made two interpolations in an attempt to clarify the verse.

In [the Hebrew](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/judges/1-16.htm), there is neither the name of the city nor the name of the people group. Hence, the NASB, along with [most translations](https://biblehub.com/judges/1-16.htm), omits both.

The GNT, however, looking at their route, has decided that the "city of palms" refers to Jericho and that the country south of Arad was settled by the Amalekites.

So they include those to help bridge the cultural gap that makes the original references unclear to us thousands of years later.